# Regular Expressions. Find unknown length string excluding character combinations

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-negation

I am new to regex and I spent half of my day to solve this question. I tried to search for answers, but couldn't find similar example.

I need to match strings if their end does not include char combinations such as (L|R|MIR)..

---

My tries:

1. `1234.567.89.w001.*(?!R|L|MIR)\.dwg`
2. `1234.567.89.w001[^.]*(?!R|L|MIR)$\.dwg`

and more..

---

Possible outcomes:

1. 1234.567.89.w001.dwg                               TRUE
2. 1234.567.89.w001 some random extensions.dwg        TRUE
3. 1234.567.89.w001-MIR some random text or no.dwg    FALSE (MIR included after base name)
4. 1234.567.89.w001_L.dwg                             FALSE (L included after base name)
5. 1234.567.89.w001-R.dwg                             FALSE (R included after base name)
6. 1234.567.89.w001R.dwg                              FALSE
7. 1234.567.89.w001MIR.dwg                            FALSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not an expert at regex but when I tested this, outcomes 1 and 2 returned true, the rest returned false.

```
1234\.567\.89\.w001(?!.*(R|L|MIR)).*\.dwg
```

You were very close, you just needed to include the 'allow any character' .* inside the lookahead.

Also make sure you \ escape the . because in regex the . character means any character not the . itself.

If you're new to regex, try using https://regex101.com. Thats what I use to check mine.